# Optimize Mysql table and / or query

Tags: mysql

I got this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `company` c LEFT JOIN
        contacts2company c2c ON c2c.companyID = c.companyID LEFT JOIN
        contacts con ON con.contactsID = c2c.contactsID
```

and it takes like 2 min to execute. 
company table is about 40K records,
contacts2company is 9K
contacts is about 9k
c.companyID is primary key
con.contactsID is also primary key.
any ideas on how to optimize db structure to run this faster?

Comment: Do you have indexes on your tables?

Comment: You could post a question on stackoverflow including the structure of your tables/indexes, the EXPLAIN plan for the query, and justification for using a left join and reading every row in your dataset in a single query.

Comment: Primary keys are always indexed, but what about your `contacts2company` table? And the `LEFT JOIN`s are correct I assume?

Comment: What about `c2c.contactsID` and `c2c.companyID`?

Comment: please post the EXPLAIN from your select

Answer (score 0):

Replace the * in your query with the columns that you need to query. For example:

```
SELECT c.companyID, con.contactName FROM `company` c LEFT JOIN
        contacts2company c2c ON c2c.companyID = c.companyID LEFT JOIN
        contacts con ON con.contactsID = c2c.contactsID
```

This should reduce the amount of time it takes your query to execute.